# Is it possible to add custom attributes to a web.config element?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, web.config-transform

I am investigating using web.config transforms to manage a fairly large set of rewrite rules. The rewrite rules are stored in the web.config, and look something like the following:

```
<rule name="somename">
  <match filterByTags="Img, Link, Script" pattern="^/content/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Rewrite" value="http://foo.com/{R:1}"  />
</rule>
```

I can write a transform file like the following:

```
<rule name="somename"
      xdt:Locator="Match(name)"
      xdt:Transform="Replace">
  <match filterByTags="Img, Link, Script" pattern="^/content/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Rewrite" value="http://foo.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

This works, but it relies on the name attribute, which is something that a developer might edit. What I want to do is add an extra attribute to the action, and then match on that. So the web.config would be:

```
<rule name="somename">
  <match filterByTags="Img, Link, Script" pattern="^/content/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action extraid="content" type="Rewrite" value="http://foo.com/{R:1}"  />
</rule>
```

And then the transform can be greatly simplified to:

```
<action
    xdt:Locator="Match(extraid)"
    xdt:Transform="Replace"
    extraid="content"
  type="Rewrite" value="http://foo.com/{R:1}" />
```

This makes the transform far less likely to be broken by accident, and makes the transform itself much smaller and simpler. The transformation tool accepts this and works correctly, but the source web.config is invalid, as it looks like I can't add attributes to web.config elements. Both Visual Studio and IIS/ASP.NET complain about the unrecognized attribute. I've tried creating a namespace for the attribute, but that doesn't help.

Note that I have attempted a variety of approaches, and they all result in either a compile failure or runtime error (500 error - unrecognized attribute).

Is there some way to add attributes to an existing configuration section/element?

Comment: Did you try it?  The extra attribute will almost certainly cause no harm, though I'm not sure whether it might cause a syntax warning in Visual Studio.

Comment: I did try it. Visual studio complained with or without a namespace. The build failed without a namespace, and ASP.NET crashed (500) with a namespace.

Comment: KISS - don't over complicate - you are making non-issues into problems. Developers edit stuff all the time - adding another attribute doesn't prohibit  editing.

Comment: True, but I'd also like the simpler transform file. Instead of having to specify the whole element structure, it would only need the one element.